# Não consigo clonar projeto no Gitlab

Tags: ssh, gitlab, rsa

Estou com problema ao tentar clonar projetos no Gitlab, eu tenho duas contas no Gitlab onde acabei gerando um SSH Key pra uma e o RSA pra outra, logo, eu consigo atualizar qual conta está conectada no meu computador apenas desativando o token e colocando o certo pra cada conta e vice-versa, eu digito `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` e aparece a conta que realmente tenho permissão pra clonar, mas quando eu tento clonar, aparece este erro.

```
Cloning into 'jobfygo'...
Username for 'https://gitlab.com': vagnerwentz
Password for 'https://vagnerwentz@gitlab.com': 
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/jobfy/backend/jobfygo.git/'
```

Comment: O username e password estão corretos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, utilizei o RSA Key que gerei e troquei ele.